# Ionic icons hover effect

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, icons, ionicons

I am using ion-icons as part of a website I am building.  How do I select an individual icon in css?  Everytime I try to add a class or an id to the link it disappears on my webiste.

I would like to take 3 different social media icons and change the color when the mouse hovers over them.  IE, when you hover over the FaceBook Icon it changes the color to the facebook blue.

Here is one of the examples I am using:

```
 <ul class="social-links">
     <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: heyy use hover effect in css

Comment: Can you give an example of trying to add an Id or class to show where you are adding it and what CSS it has as adding just an id say to the anchor element doesn’t sound as though it should make the icon ‘disappear’. Preferably create a snippet so we can see for ourselves. Thanks.

Comment: @Aahad, I understand that is the effect that I am supposed to use.  I am having a hard time selecting the html object to apply it to.

Comment: @AHaworth, I tried in several different spots.  I tried to add a class like this class="instaLogo" inside the anchor tag and again inside the ion-icon tag after the name.  Everytime I did that, the icon disappeared from my page, but the facebook one remained.  I could see the "outline" of it but it was not visible.    `<li><a href="#" class="instaLogo"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a></li>`  and ` <li><a href="#"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram" class="instaLogo"></ion-icon></a></li>

Comment: and the css looks something like this: `.instaLogo:hover {
    color: #1877f2;
}

Comment: I have put the code from your question and from your comments together and they work fine. See the snippet in my answer. This must mean there is something else causing the problem. You will need to show more - for example the social-links class - and preferably create a snippet which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the code given in the question plus that added in subsequent comments I have put together a small test and it seems to be working fine.

This means there must be something 'further up' that is disturbing the icon set-up. Could is be in the CSS social-links class?

Here is the working snippet. Note, the icons turn red on hover just to make them different from the standard color.

```html
<head>
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css"/>-->
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css"/>

<style>
.instaLogo:hover { color: #1877f2; color:red;} /*change to red just to show that the color is actually changing */
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <ul class="social-links">
     <li><a href="#" class="instaLogo"><ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon></a></li>
     <li><a href="#" class="instaLogo"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></a></li>
 </ul>
 </body>
```